# Xdebug Profiler with Zend Server - No output / dumps

Tags: php, profiling, xdebug, zend-server

I cant seem to get Xdebug to dump out anything from the profiler. Xdebug itself works just fine, but the profiler is having issues, these are my `php.ini` settings:

-

```
[XDebug] 
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.remote_enable=1 
xdebug.remote_port=9000 
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="C:\Zend\ZendServer\tmp\xdebug-profiler"  
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
```

Anyone experienced this, or have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Xdebug will not go ahead and create the output directory for you, I created `C:\Zend\ZendServer\tmp\xdebug-profiler` and the problem is now solved.